# Upload images with bootstrap-markdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, markdown, image-uploading

I'm using [bootstrap-markdown](https://github.com/toopay/bootstrap-markdown) , When i'm trying to insert image i can only insert it from web , Is there any solution to unable upload from local machine ?

```
    <form>
        <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title?" />
        <textarea id="myEditor" name="content" data-provide="markdown" rows="10"></textarea>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input name="publish" type="checkbox"> Publish
        </label>
        <hr/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this module :
https://github.com/inacho/bootstrap-markdown-editor

Here is an example to activate upload :

```
$('#myEditor').markdownEditor({
  imageUpload: true, // Activate the option
  uploadPath: 'upload.php' // Path of the server side script that receive the files
});
```

Here is a [documentation](https://github.com/inacho/bootstrap-markdown-editor#implementing-the-image-upload)